# Leave empty line breaks PHP CS Fixer

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, php-cs-fixer

In my code I prefer to have more than a single line break between methods inside a class to make browsing code a little easier, and I've tried a bunch of rules that sound related to keeping/removing white space, but I cannot find a rule to ignore empty line breaks.

Take the following snippet

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }





    /**
     * Undocumented function
     *
     * @param [type] $param1
     * @param [type] $param2
     */
    public function bar($param1, $param2)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

php-cs-fixer will remove the white space between the two methods like so

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Undocumented function
     *
     * @param [type] $param1
     * @param [type] $param2
     */
    public function bar($param1, $param2)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I find this harder to read when scanning through a class file, so I'd like to tell `php-cs-fixer` to leave the empty line breaks alone. Is this possible?

I've tried setting `no_extra_blank_lines` to an empty array, or to false as this sounded like the right setting, but it doesn't appear to have any affect.

FYI I'm using VS Code with this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=junstyle.php-cs-fixer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After leaving this for a couple of days, I've come back to it and managed to find the appropriate rule.

If I change `method_separation => false` the line breaks are left in tact in class files.